# Optimize processing in backend side, select using user-defined function in where clause, spring boot hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, caching, user-defined-functions

I am trying to get all parking lot (each parking lot has Lat, Lng attribute) by scanning with radius.

I have created a user-defined-function to calculate distance between 2 point and named it GET_DISTANCE_IN_KILOMETRE in the database.

Let I describe what I want to achieve:

As user want to "find all parking lot near hear", LatLng of his/her current location, together with a default radius in kilometres will be sent as request to the server. Then it will query in the database, search for parking lot near his/her location by iterate all of parking lot table row and with each row, calculate the distance between his/her location to the parking lot, then get all parking lot within a specific radius by compare the recently created distance attribute with the radius param.

Each request seem to need at least 400-500 milliseconds to response to the client. My parking-lot table now has about 500 rows. I wonder if is there any approach for better performance? Assume that in the near future, the parking lot table have 1000 rows or 10000 rows or more, what approach can I change ?

I recently read about caching in backend side. I also wonder if it can be use to optimize this case or not ?

The code below is the sample query which I wrote for currently using at this developing time.
I look forward to hearing from you all ! Thank you for helping me !

```
DECLARE
    @LATITUDE FLOAT
DECLARE
    @LONGITUDE FLOAT
DECLARE
    @RADIUS SMALLINT

SET @LATITUDE = 10.784122211291663
SET @LONGITUDE = 106.71152489259839
SET @RADIUS = 3

SELECT TOP 10 P.ID,
              PLI.NAME,
              P.PARKING_LOT_TYPE_ID,
              P.LATITUDE,
              P.LONGITUDE,
              DISTANCE
FROM PARKING_LOT P
         INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM PARKING_LOT_INFORMATION) AS PLI ON PLI.ID = P.ID
         INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PL.ID, dbo.GET_DISTANCE_IN_KILOMETRE(@LATITUDE, @LONGITUDE, PL.LATITUDE, PL.LONGITUDE) AS DISTANCE
    FROM PARKING_LOT PL) AS PL
                    ON P.ID = PL.ID AND DISTANCE <= @RADIUS AND IS_AVAILABLE = 1
                        AND CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()) BETWEEN P.OPENING_HOUR AND P.CLOSING_HOUR
ORDER BY DISTANCE
```

Comment: Don't write your own function.  Use the GIS capabilities available in whatever database you are using.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. Is there anything else you recommend for optimise the performance ?